# Role Based Session Expiring Duration in Asp.Net Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

My Application is having 3 types of Asp.Net User Roles. Currently every user is having Cookie Expiration Time of 10 days. I am able to set this at Startup Class using this code:

```html
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(10, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    SlidingExpiration=true,
}
```

The problem here is that this sliding expiring time is applied to all kind of users in the system. I am not able to figure out how can we set the expiring time of cookie based on the Role of the user who've just logged in.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.authenticationproperties(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks Cuong, thanks for reminding me the AuthenticationProperties Class, I achieved what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

While logging in user you can check the roles of user and according to his role you can assign sliding expiration and ExpireTimeSpan's value.

Simply create a function like below to get these value and call it while creating authentication cookie.

```
public AuthInfoDTO GetAuthInfo(List<string> roles)
        {
            AuthInfoDTO obj = new AuthInfoDTO();

            if (roles.Any(x => x == "Admin"))
            {
                obj.SlidingExpiration = true;
                ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(10, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                obj.SlidingExpiration = false;
                ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            return obj;
        }
```

also create a DTO class like below:

```
 public class AuthInfoDTO
    {
        public bool SlidingExpiration { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan ExpireTimeSpan { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I've got a confusion. Where shall I assign the AuthInfoDTO object so that it may come in effect?